# Tableau doesn't support multiple selection of values in parameter

Tags: tableau-api

We have made parameter of State which can filter the view on selection of specific state. But we need multiple selection of states at a time( for example, checkbox in state parameter). But currently, it is not possible to have multiple selection in parameter.

We don't want to use filter as we wanted to change the text of one option, so we have to use parameter only.

Is there anyway to have multiple selections of parameter in tableau?

Comment: Tableau dosen't support multi-select parameters directly.  You mentioned you can't use filters because you need to 'change the text' for one state. Perhaps you can use **'Edit Alias'** for that one state to change the text ? That will let you use filters, without going through some hacky work-around to implement multi-select parameter.

Comment: Tableau don't support multiple selection in parameter. Only available with filters.

Comment: Do you need to use a parameter? You can filter on a field like State, and show a filter control that allows multiple selection. If all you want to do is filter, then you shouldn't need a parameter. Or you can define a set based on the State field, and choose the members of your set -- but you can't (currently) show an interactive control for sets on a dashboard.